# Opencv application crashes at runtime with error code 0x0000142

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, dll, crash

I have openCV and minGW installed with codeblock IDE following the instructions found here http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/
i tried the simple image loading program in the article and the build process went fine. but when i tried running the output program, it crashes with the error message "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application."
I used Dependency Walker to see if the program failed to load dll module and here's the output screen of Dependency Walker
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9iaftdt8atjwpl/Screenshot%202013-11-05%2022.21.45.png
i am not used to DW but as i can see in its output screen, some openCV dll failed to load and the loaded Windows DLL were 64 bit instead of 32 bit (as minGW is 32 bit).
I can't figure out why as i already configure the Path environment variable for the bin directory of openCV and the app still can not load the dll modules. And i think that Windows will automatically load the proper 32 bit DLLs when a 32 bit app is run but this situation the app still failed to load.
Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the path is proper - you can just copy dlls to the build directory. If it would work, problem in path.